# Detect when a flash object is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've looked around on SO on this topic like this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896126/detect-if-objects-are-loaded-javascript). Also this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440338/how-to-determine-when-an-embedded-flash-object-is-loaded). But for one I'm not using a YouTube flash object and also I'm not using an image. Below is a simple AJAX request which retrieves data to populate a table.

```
    $(document).ready(onDocumentReady);

    function onDocumentReady(){
      $('#Recorded').addClass('border').click(changeToRecorded);
      $('#Pending').addClass('border').click(changeToPending);
      $('#main').addClass('scroll');
      $('#entries').addClass('main');
    }

    function changeToRecorded(){
      $('#entries').hide();
      $('#main').html("Loading");
      $.get("getData.php",{ status: "R" },requestComplete);
    }

    function changeToPending(){
      $('#entries').hide();
      $('#main').html("Loading");
      $.get("getData.php",{ status: "P" },requestComplete);
    }

    function requestComplete(data){
      $('#main').html('<table id="entries"></table>');
      $('#entries').addClass('main');
      $('#entries').html(data);
      $('#entries').show();
    }
```

getData.php includes some embed flash objects which populates the table id "entries". The problem I have is that it shows "Loading" during the AJAX request however after there is still a delay to load the embed objects into the table. Using jQuery or any other javascript method is there a way to detect when all embed objects are done loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not. Flash is a streaming technology so technically it's hard to define what "loaded" means. Has it loaded the first frame? Has it finished the timeline? Has it retreived all external movies? Have all the preload resources loaded? etc...

If you have the source code for the Flash movies you can perform some callouts to JS, otherwise there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Can I at least not show the table for a few seconds after the AJAX request?

Comment: use window.setTimeout to delay an action for an arbitrary amount of time